# javascript loop going mental

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a simple javascript loop on my php page that just adds 1 to a value every second. Well, the loop runs every second, and increments the value.

```
var test = 0;

function go() {
  test = test + 1;
  setTimeout(go, 1000);
  }

go();
```

This works fine.

Problem is, the PHP page this runs on is actually inside a div tag that refreshes every 10 seconds. After 10 seconds, the count goes haywire, adding 2 every second, then 3, then 4, etc.

How can I stop this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, it's a browser problem. So: what browser are you using?

Comment: Since it increments the number added every time, I'd suggest you're starting another `go()` function running every time the page refreshes.

Comment: chrome.........Is there a way to cancel all `go` occurances before i run it?

Comment: i think that every time the php refreshes, it calls go(), which starts another setTimeout loop.  you need to find a way to clear the old timeouts.

Comment: There is no way this can run on a php page.  At best its the html page a php script produces.  You can try something like `if(!test){go()}` which will only call `go()` if the test is not already populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the problem appears to be multiple instances of your function running, increasing on each refresh/update of the page, I'd suggest adding a sanity-check to your function:

```
var test = 0;
var running = running || false;

function go() {
    if (running) {
        // if an instance of go() is already running, the function quits
        return false;
    }
    else {
        running = true; // as the test variable survives I assume this will, too
        test = test + 1;
        setTimeout(go, 1000);
    }
  }

go();
```

As it's probable that `test` is going to be overwritten every time the page updates, I'd suggest ensuring that the assignation isn't going to overwrite a pre-existing count:

```
var test = test || 0;
var running = running || false;

function go() {
    if (running) {
        // if an instance of go() is already running, the function quits
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var running = true; // as the test variable survives I assume this will, too
        test = test + 1;
        setTimeout(go, 1000);
    }
  }

go();
```

Bear in mind that you could simply use the existence of the `test` variable to determine whether the function is currently running or not, but because I don't know if you'll be using that for other purposes I've chosen to create another variable for that purpose (which should hold either `true` or `false` Boolean values).

Answer (score 1):

Change: `go()` to `if(!test){ go() }`

You'll also have to mend your `test` variable.  So `var test = test || 0;`